# Server Error 500 in php page

Tags: php, html, server

I have a problem with a PHP page returning a server error 500.  This only happens in a single page. I spoke to the host and they told me that I have an issue in my code.

This is the content of the file exhibiting the error

```html
    <?php
define('APP_URL', 'http://mysit.com/');
define('APP_ID', 'xxxxx');
define('APP_SECRET', 'xxxxx');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
     <title>test</title>
     <meta property="og:title" content="Which of your friends are secretly smoking?" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo APP_URL . 'result.php?id=<?php echo trim(htmlentities($_GET['id']))'; ?>"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="test" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo APP_URL . 'converted/<?php echo $_GET['id']'; ?>.jpg" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo APP_ID; ?>" />
  <meta name="medium" content="image" />
     
   </head>
   <body>
    <a href="./">test</a> 

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<?php echo APP_URL . 'result.php?id=<?php echo trim(htmlentities($_GET['id']))'; ?>"/>
```

should be:

```
<?= APP_URL.'result.php?id='.htmlentities(trim($_GET['id'])) ?>
```

The same type of update also needs to be made to the other line that contains embedded <?php tags.

Comment: thnx :) This also suffers from damage 

`<?php echo APP_URL . 'converted/<?php echo $_GET['id']'; ?>`

Comment: Thats good
thank you very much
`<?= APP_URL.'converted/'.htmlentities(trim($_GET['id'])) ?>`